# Django and Eclipse, console

Tags: django, eclipse

I'm using Django with Eclipse and I figured out you can start and stop the server through Eclipse and the output appears in the console.  This is great except that there's a delay between when the event happens, and when the result appears.  Usually, in order to get something to show up on the console I have to make a change to the code and save it (django then reloads it) or I have to restart the server.  In the bottom right it says "Refresh on finish" so maybe that has something to do with it, but I can't figure out how to make it display the console output live as it's happening

Comment: Are you referring to Django's `runserver`?  Which version of Django are you using, and which version of Eclipse?  Being more specific will payoff in better answers.

Comment: I am referring to Django's runserver.  I'm using Django 1.2.1 and Eclipse 3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6, Django 1.2.1, Eclipse 3.5, PyDev ), I see the same behavior that I see at work (Windows 7, Python 2.6, Django 1.2.1, Eclipse 3.6, PyDev):

When I start the Django runserver from within Eclipse, it's output goes to a console window, except for the first startup messages.  Thus the first message will either be an access log entry, or an error trace.  Once you update a class that is part of the Django project, you will get a server startup message, then any subsequent access/error log entries.

```
[23/Aug/2010 23:59:52] "GET /foo/bar/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27085
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.2.1, using settings 'foo.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[24/Aug/2010 00:01:06] "GET /foo/bar/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27365
```

The only delay that I perceive is while re-running a rather labor-intensive set of web-services, but even that is a massive improvement over the earlier versions.

Comment: I'm seeing behavior like that.  It spits out console output only after saving and reloading something.  It's annoying but I guess I can live with it if I don't have any option

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but does your computer have enough memory?  Eclipse is a serious memory hog, and adding Python plus Django plus Firefox and a bunch of tabs open can really tax your system...